# jQuery: attach previous event handler removed with off

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, event-handling

I have an AJAX call. During this call the button has to be disabled.
Then, as the call ends, the `click` event to the button has to be reactivated.

I do it with this code. Unfortunately, the click event works only the first time

```
$('#reload_btn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).off('click');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax/stat.php',
        data: {use: 'get'},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#reload_btn').attr('src', 'files/reload_btn.gif');
        },
        success: function(result){
            $('#ajax').html(result);
        },
        error: function(data){
            $('#ajax').html('Error!');
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#reload_btn').on('click');
            $('#reload_btn').attr('src', 'files/reload_btn.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Is there any way to reattach the `click` event without calling an external function?

Answer (score 2):

You can re-attach the handler if you change 2 lines: store a reference to the function:

```
$('#reload_btn').on('click', f = function(){
```

and pass it to `.click`:

```
    complete: function(){
        $('#reload_btn').on('click', f);
```